# Can we handle the directory browsing requesting via IHTTPHandler in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, httphandler

Can we handle the directory browsing requesting via IHTTPHandler in asp.net, as I have some requirement when the clicks on browse directory, at that time it should first land into a handler so that i can update the status[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPzsl.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.